# Is there something wrong with casting $_REQUEST to object?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, object

In PHP is wrong to cast `$_REQUEST` to an object to manage it more easily?

```
$request = (object) $_REQUEST;
if(isset($request->submit) && isset($request->text) && !empty($request->text))
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

**EDIT**: i mean any unexpected side effect?

Comment: Apart from unexpected side effects?

Comment: What benefit do you gain by doing this?

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb and say **no** it's not wrong, but I supposed it really depends how you define "wrong". There might be some situations where it would be pointless, and some situations where it would be better. But this is a somewhat subjective, "discussion" type question that's not *really* the right sort of question for SO (IMHO).

Comment: Why is it more easily managable?

Comment: I'm using something similar, but specifically retain array syntax support (`ArrayObject`). Just converting an array into an object brings no benefits.

Comment: Edit: $_REQUEST is not deprecated for now, just considered as a bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say there's nothing wrong with this except obviously the little added time you'll get. What I would do though is run the $_REQUEST array through a cleaner function to validate and clean up the variables. This way you can always know that if your using the object version of the $_REQEUST that it's safe to use.

**Update**

I would go as far as saying this is probably best practice in the world of modern web applications. I mean look at the MVC frameworks you use (Zend, CodeIgniter, CakePHP etc) they all clean the $_REQUEST, $_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER etc and convert them to objects.

Remeber that the overhead on something like this would be so minimal you wouldn't even notice it. The time PHP takes to parse and output a page is so small, usually smaller than a DOM request for one image.

Comment: What do you mean with validate and clean up?

Comment: Check for invalid characters, possible SQL injection attacks and any other data that may be harmful to the app. Remember anything recieved through $_REQUEST should NOT be trusted.

Comment: Ensure that your user didn't inputed `'<script type="text/javascript">alert('You g0T h4xEd!!1');</script>' in `$_REQUEST['order_amount']` in your e-commerce website.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing I can see that is ***wrong*** with that.

It will just allow you to access the associative array as an object.

Answer (score 2):

Not to be argumentative but I don't see how this makes it any easier to manage the `$_REQUEST` variable. You could write the same line of code like so:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && isset($_REQUEST['text']) && !empty($_REQUEST['text']))
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

Also, there can be some issues with array keys that don't translate into object property names properly. Take for example `$_REQUEST['var name']`. Completely legitimate array name but translate the array into an object and you'll be sorely disappointed at the results.

However, if you trust your users that much and want to spend the extra clock cycles creating a new object you could always brute force it.

```
$request = new stdclass;
foreach($_REQUEST as $field => $value){
    $request->$field = $value;
}
```